# Need help getting a MERGE statement to work

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

My SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 database has two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "ListDetails" (
    ListDetailId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ListId          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
    CountryId       VARCHAR(3)          NULL REFERENCES "Countries"      ( CountryId ) DEFAULT 'USA',
    LocaleCode      VARCHAR(3)          NULL REFERENCES "Locales"        ( LocaleCode ),
    Plate           VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
    HashedPlate     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NULL,
    AlarmClassId    INT                 NULL REFERENCES "AlarmClasses"   ( AlarmClassId ),
    BeginDate       DATETIME            NULL,
    EndDate         DATETIME            NULL,
    ListPriorityId  INT                 NULL REFERENCES "ListPriorities" ( ListPriorityId ),
    VehicleTypeId   INT                 NULL REFERENCES "VehicleTypes"   ( VehicleTypeId ),
    PlateClassId    INT                 NULL REFERENCES "PlateClasses"   ( PlateClassId ),
    MakeId          INT                 NULL REFERENCES "VehicleBrands"  ( VehicleBrandId ),
    ModelId         INT                 NULL REFERENCES "VehicleModels"  ( VehicleModelId ),
    "Year"          INT                 NULL,
    ColorId         INT                 NULL REFERENCES "VehicleColors"  ( VehicleColorId ),
    Notes           VARCHAR(8000)       NULL,
    OfficerNotes    VARCHAR(8000)       NULL,
    IsNewRow        BIT                 NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    CreatedDate     DATETIME            NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    i_active        SMALLINT            NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    ModifyDate      DATETIME            NULL,
    Subscriber      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NULL,
    FromToVersion   BIGINT              NOT NULL,
    FromVersion     BIGINT,
    InstanceId      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "ListDetailsLoad" ( 
    ListDetailId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
    ListId          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
    CountryId       VARCHAR(3)          NULL,
    LocaleCode      VARCHAR(3)          NULL,
    Plate           VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
    HashedPlate     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NULL,
    AlarmClassId    INT                 NULL,
    BeginDate       DATETIME            NULL,
    EndDate         DATETIME            NULL,
    ListPriorityId  INT                 NULL,
    VehicleTypeId   INT                 NULL,
    PlateClassId    INT                 NULL,
    MakeId          INT                 NULL,
    ModelId         INT                 NULL,
    "Year"          INT                 NULL,
    ColorId         INT                 NULL,
    Notes           VARCHAR(8000)       NULL,
    OfficerNotes    VARCHAR(8000)       NULL,
    Subscriber      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NULL,
    InstanceId      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL
) NOT TRANSACTIONAL;
```

My program (written in C#) performs a bulk copy into the ListDetailsLoad table and then runs a stored procedure.  The stored procedure's job is to move the data into the ListDetails table.  Here's the stored procedure:

```
MERGE INTO "ListDetails" AS dst
USING "ListDetailsLoad" AS src
ON dst.ListDetailId = src.ListDetailId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET ListDetailId    = src.ListDetailId,
        ListId          = src.ListId,
        CountryId       = src.CountryId,
        LocaleCode      = src.LocalCode,
        Plate           = src.Plate,
        HashedPlate     = src.HashedPlate,
        AlarmClassId    = src.AlarmClassId,
        BeginDate       = src.BeginDate,
        EndDate         = src.EndDate,
        ListPriorityId  = src.ListPriorityId,
        VehicleTypeId   = src.VehicleType,
        PlateClassId    = src.PlateClassId,
        MakeId          = src.MakeId,
        ModelId         = src.ModelId,
        "Year"          = src."Year",
        ColorId         = src.ColorId,
        Notes           = src.Notes,
        OfficerNotes    = src.OfficerNotes,
        ModifyDate      = NOW(),
        FromToVersion   = dbVersion.NEXTVAL,
        FromVersion     = NULL,
        Subscriber      = src.Subscriber,
        InstanceId      = src.InstanceId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        ( ListDetailId, ListId,        CountryId,  LocaleCode,     Plate,         HashedPlate,
          AlarmClassId, BeginDate,     EndDate,    ListPriorityId, VehicleTypeId, PlateClassId,
          MakeId,       ModelId,       "Year",     ColorId,        Notes,         OfficerNotes,
          ModifyDate,   FromToVersion, Subscriber, FromVersion,    InstanceId )
    VALUES
        ( src.ListDetailId, src.ListId,        src.CountryId,  src.LocaleCode,     src.Plate,         src.HashedPlate,
          src.AlarmClassId, src.BeginDate,     src.EndDate,    src.ListPriorityId, src.VehicleTypeId, src.PlateClassId,
          src.MakeId,       src.ModelId,       src."Year",     src.ColorId,        src.Notes,         src.OfficerNotes,
          NOW(),            dbVersion.NEXTVAL,     NULL,       src.Subscriber, src.InstanceId );

    TRUNCATE TABLE "ListDetailsLoad";
END;
```

This compiles fine. The problem is when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
Could not execute statement.  Column "ListDetailId" found in more than one table or it is used more than once in the SELECT list -- it needs a correlation name.
```

How do I fix the MERGE statement?

Comment: can you please tell me how you formatted that create statement so nicesly?>

Comment: I used spaces and tabs in the original, lining everything up as I wanted.  When I created the post, I copied & pasted the code into Notepad and replaced all of the tabs with 4 spaces, then lined everything back up.  The alignment in the post isn't exactly what was in the original, but it's OK.

Comment: what a pain .i thought you had an automated solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you what the problem is. :)

On the left side of your `UPDATE` statement, there are no correlation names, and it doesn't know which `ListDetailId` to update. This should work:

```
USING "ListDetailsLoad" AS src
ON dst.ListDetailId = src.ListDetailId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET dst.ListDetailId    = src.ListDetailId,
        dst.ListId          = src.ListId,
        dst.CountryId       = src.CountryId,
        dst.LocaleCode      = src.LocalCode,
        dst.Plate           = src.Plate,
        dst.HashedPlate     = src.HashedPlate,
        dst.AlarmClassId    = src.AlarmClassId,
        dst.BeginDate       = src.BeginDate,
        dst.EndDate         = src.EndDate,
        dst.ListPriorityId  = src.ListPriorityId,
        dst.VehicleTypeId   = src.VehicleType,
        dst.PlateClassId    = src.PlateClassId,
        dst.MakeId          = src.MakeId,
        dst.ModelId         = src.ModelId,
        dst."Year"          = src."Year",
        dst.ColorId         = src.ColorId,
        dst.Notes           = src.Notes,
        dst.OfficerNotes    = src.OfficerNotes,
        dst.ModifyDate      = NOW(),
        dst.FromToVersion   = dbVersion.NEXTVAL,
        dst.FromVersion     = NULL,
        dst.Subscriber      = src.Subscriber,
        dst.InstanceId      = src.InstanceId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        ( ListDetailId, ListId,        CountryId,  LocaleCode,     Plate,         HashedPlate,
          AlarmClassId, BeginDate,     EndDate,    ListPriorityId, VehicleTypeId, PlateClassId,
          MakeId,       ModelId,       "Year",     ColorId,        Notes,         OfficerNotes,
          ModifyDate,   FromToVersion, Subscriber, FromVersion,    InstanceId )
    VALUES
        ( src.ListDetailId, src.ListId,        src.CountryId,  src.LocaleCode,     src.Plate,         src.HashedPlate,
          src.AlarmClassId, src.BeginDate,     src.EndDate,    src.ListPriorityId, src.VehicleTypeId, src.PlateClassId,
          src.MakeId,       src.ModelId,       src."Year",     src.ColorId,        src.Notes,         src.OfficerNotes,
          NOW(),            dbVersion.NEXTVAL,     NULL,       src.Subscriber, src.InstanceId );

    TRUNCATE TABLE "ListDetailsLoad";
END;
```

Comment: While you were right, the correlation name on the left needed to be dst, not src.  There were other problems caused by me (I misspelled a few field names on the right side of the UPDATE and I go the order of the field names wrong on the last line of the INSERT.  But once I fixed all of those, it runs fine.  Thanks!